# How to make deep copy of collection in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections, data-class

I need to make replica of existing collection and here is how I do it:

```kotlin
data class MyObject(var type: Int, var index: Int)

fun main() {
    val a1 = listOf(MyObject(1,1), MyObject(2,2))
    val a2 = mutableListOf<MyObject>()
    a1.forEach { a2.add(it.copy()) }
    a2[0].index = 5 // should not change first element in a1
    println("a1: ${a1[0]} ${a1[1]}\na2: ${a2[0]} ${a2[1]}")
}
```

Out:

```
a1: MyObject(type=1, index=1) MyObject(type=2, index=2)
a2: MyObject(type=1, index=5) MyObject(type=2, index=2)
```

Is it proper way to make deep copy of a collection or Kotlin has some idiomatic approach to that?

Comment: `val a2 = a1.map { it.copy() }` ?